# Is it possible to develop mobile app with Django

Tags: django

I have been learning python lately and know I am on the stage of thinking to develop an application and I decided to develop web app and mobile app using the language I have been learning (python) I then decided to use Django to develop my web app however I heard that instagram was built with Django and I wondered if it is possible to develop mobile app using Django.
**My Question Is **
         Is it possible to develop mobile app using Django?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android/iOS app with Django as backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790886/android-ios-app-with-django-as-backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot develop a native mobile app with Python and Django.

You can only use it to create a regular Web Application (Backend) that is then opened on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, I just found out that it's actually possible**

1. Use the Django Rest Framework to serve as the backend for something like
   React Native.
2. Build a traditional website for mobile and then run it through a tool like PhoneGap.
3. Use the standard Android app tools and use Django to serve and process data through API requests.

Got this solution from
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337572/is-it-possible-to-make-a-mobile-app-in-django)