# Is it possible to make a mobile app in Django?

Tags: python, android, django, django-models, mobile

I was wondering if it is possible for me to use Django code I have for my website and somehow use that in a mobile app, in a framework such as, for example, Flutter.

So is it possible to use the Django backend I have right now and use it in a mobile app?

So like the `models`, `views` etc...

Comment: you could write APIs using Django rest framework and connect to app

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Yes. There are a couple ways you could do it**

1. Use the Django Rest Framework to serve as the backend for something like React Native.
2. Build a traditional website for mobile and then run it through a tool like PhoneGap.
3. Use the standard Android app tools and use Django to serve and process data through API requests.

Comment: In 2021/2022, have things matured to the point where you'd recommend one way over the other?

Comment: Yes, if the post author can add a few words as to the trade-off and best contender out of the options or others, please add further recommendation. This site describes the Pros/cons of using PhoneGap (https://www.javatpoint.com/pros-and-cons-of-phonegap) . From what I believe, relying API requests in the app will increase latency if it is a somewhat data intensive application. So 1?

Answer (score 0):

Update for 2022: This [article from AppPresser](https://apppresser.com/phonegap-build-is-dead-here-are-some-alternatives/) provides alternatives to PhoneGap which was mentioned in the other answer.  These alternatives can be used to package web native sites as mobile apps.

The alternatives listed are:

- Bitrise
- Ionic

The honorable mentions were:

- Appcircle
- Appcenter
- CodeMagic
- Codeship